# rollapply variation - growing window functions

Tags: r, sequence

How would one use `rollapply` (or some other R function) to grow the window size as the function progresses though the data. To phrase it another way, the first apply works with the first element, the second with the first two elements, the third with the first three elements etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to apply  `min` , `max`, `sum` or `prod`, these functions already have their cumulative counterparts as:

`cummin`, `cummax`, `cumsum` and `cumprod`

To apply more exotic functions on a growing / expanding window, you can simply use `sapply`

eg

```
# your vector of interest
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

sapply(seq_along(x), function(y,n) yourfunction(y[seq_len(n)]), y = x)
```

For a basic zoo object

```
x.Date <- as.Date("2003-02-01") + c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14) - 1
x <- zoo(rnorm(5), x.Date)

# cumsum etc will work and return a zoo object
cs.zoo <- cumsum(x)

# convert back to zoo for the `sapply` solution
# here `sum`
foo.zoo <- zoo(sapply(seq_along(x), function(n,y) sum(y[seq_len(n)]), y= x), index(x))


identical(cs.zoo, foo.zoo)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how could I get this to work with zoo objects?

Comment: @Craig . I think it's been long enough. You should accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

From peering at the documentation at `?zooapply` I think this will do what you want, where `a` is your matrix and `sum` can be any function:

```
a <- cbind(1:5,1:5)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    2    2
# [3,]    3    3
# [4,]    4    4
# [5,]    5    5
rollapply(a,width=seq_len(nrow(a)),sum,align="right")
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    3    3
# [3,]    6    6
# [4,]   10   10
# [5,]   15   15
```

But [mnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385941/)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271536/697568) seems sufficient and more generalizable.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @mnel's answer:

> For more exotic functions you can simply use sapply

and if the `sapply` approach takes too long, you may be better off formulating your function iteratively.